# Inputmask jquery plugin always gives the textbox initial focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using the Robin Herbots [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) to mask a textbox, and it works fine except it always forces the textbox to have initial focus when the page loads. My code is pretty straightforward

```
$("#TextBox3").inputmask("999-99-9999");
```

I tried setting focus in the codebehind page with no luck, though I can fix it by calling focus at the end of document.ready

```
$("#TextBox4").focus();
```

This seems like a hacky solution though, does anyone know how to turn off this 'feature?' I see no mention of it anywhere in the documentation, and my javascript skills are nowhere near good enough to find it in the source.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I explained my problem, gave my code, and explained what I've tried. What exactly is the problem

Comment: I countered with +1, the question looks well formed. But the robin herbots in title seems a bit spammy. Inputmask is plenty

Comment: I put the Robin Herbots part there because I saw another question with it in the title; there are a few different input mask plugins, i wanted to make sure readers knew which one I used

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm looking forward to remove this focus behavior.